# Catch redirect from another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a question about redirection 301 or 302.

For ex. i have domain `www.example.com`.

It's a good site with a good domain history. Some 'BAD' webmasters make sometimes a redirect from `bad-histories` domain with search bans to redirect it to good domains to downgrade good sites in search system query as Google.

So question is: is it possible to know, have someone made this `bad-redirect`?

As i understand in each html response html headers are transmitted. May by there is a way to catch this responses to detect such redirects?

Is it well-known practice?

Or it is impossible and it's like paranoia?

Answer (score 0):

I think is paranoia, but major browsers still keep the referrer in the redirection and can be read at destination. In php is:

```
$referral = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

you can trap all referrer urls in a log file and I have no idea how to filter out good sites. this way you will discover only redirects only from websites heaving some traffic;

Comment: Is it relate to meta http-equiv="refresh" redirection?